# Zigzag border done by css not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

at my [clients site](http://detskysvetmasa.cz) I'm using a zigzag css border (for the spead reasons I would like to avoid an image usage - I'm using different colors and so on).

My version is working fine in Chrome and Firefox (using Windows), but not in Internet Explorer. I'm using IE 11 at windws and not working. And I've no clue how to fix it, I've even added `-webkit` prefix and nothing. Anybody could help me, please?

I was inspired by [this site](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-zig-zag-border/) and it seems to working in IE 11, but I don't know what is different in my case.

```css
div.zigzag > .container {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.zigzag {
  position: relative;
}
.zigzag:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
.zigzag:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
/* blue */

.blue {
  background: #2c7892;
  color: #fff;
}
.zigzag.blue:before {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 33.333%, #2c7892 33.333%, #2c7892 66.667%, transparent 66.667%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33.333%, #2c7892 33.333%, #2c7892 66.667%, transparent 66.667%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 33.333%, #2c7892 33.333%, #2c7892 66.667%, transparent 66.667%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33.333%, #2c7892 33.333%, #2c7892 66.667%, transparent 66.667%);
  background-size: 10px 20px;
}
.zigzag.blue:after {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #2c7892 33.333%, transparent 33.333%, transparent 66.667%, #2c7892 66.667%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #2c7892 33.333%, transparent 33.333%, transparent 66.667%, #2c7892 66.667%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #2c7892 33.333%, transparent 33.333%, transparent 66.667%, #2c7892 66.667%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #2c7892 33.333%, transparent 33.333%, transparent 66.667%, #2c7892 66.667%);
  background-size: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row clearfix zigzag blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      Some Text Here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `display: table` property that is inherited from bootstraps clearfix pseudo element.

Ensure that the `display: block` property is applied by making the pseudo element more specific. Simplest method is to append "div" before the `.zigzag:before` and `.zigag:after`:

```
div.zigzag:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
div.zigzag:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
```